# Selecting multiple data ranges if condition is satisfied

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get data from an Excel sheet. If the date indicated on the column header is today's date then contents of that column need to be copied. After checking all the columns, the final data needs to be pasted in another sheet.

I have built a macro to get stock prices from web. Now I need to filter the data based on date to make it ready for making graphs. I have tried multiple variations of the below code but till now no success. Copying the ranges is the problem area.

```
Sub graphs()

Dim d As Date
Dim a As Variant
Dim f As Variant
Dim b As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim col As Variant
Dim r As Range
Dim j As Range


r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("historic price").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(50, 1)) ' this is to copy the first column with company names


b = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(1))

For x = 2 To b

    a = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("historic price").Cells(1, x)   ' below 3 lines are to extract date from column header
    f = WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", a, 10)
    d = Mid(a, 10, (f - 10))

    If d = Date Then


    r = Union(r, Range(Cells(1, x), Cells(50, x))) ' this is to add data to r


    End If

Next x

col = r.Columns.Count    ' count number of columns stored in r

r.Copy


Worksheets("graphs").Activate

Set j = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(50, col))

j.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs").Cells(1, 1).Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the new range

For example

```
Set rng1 = .Range("A1")
 Set rng2 = .Range("A2")
 Set NewRng = .Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)
```

or

```
     Set newRng = Union(rng1, rng2)
```

So you need to set r

```
set r = Union(r, Range(Cells(1, x), Cells(50, x)))
```